# javascript google map api and http://ip-api.com/json not working beginner coder having trouble

Tags: javascript, google-maps

this is my code and the lat: and lng: show not defined. When I look in chrome dev console I also see error that initMap is not a function.

```
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var  latitude;
    var  longitude;
    $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json",function(data){
         latitude=data.lat
         longitude=data.lon
   var lati=parseFloat(latitude);
   var long=parseFloat(longitude);    
                function initMap() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
           center: {
               lat:  lati
               , lng: long

          }  
          , zoom: 8

       });
           }

    });
    });


</script>
```

the map call

```
<script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=------removed--------&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initMap function will be called when the Maps API is ready.  The callback function is wrapped inside your getJSON callback and will be out of scope when invoked by the API.

Answer (score -1):

```
define('CDN','http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');
error_reporting(0);
$get = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/'),true);
date_default_timezone_set($get['timezone']);
$city ="Lahore";
$string = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
q=".$city."&units=metric&appid=f1fded24a81b4aaaf12c2eaa0acf8e69";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($string),true);
$temp = $data['main']['temp'];
$visibility = $data['visibility'];
$visibilitykm = $visibility / 1000;
$humidity = $data['main']['humidity'];
echo "Temprature: ".$temp."<br>"; 
echo "humidity: ".$humidity;
```

Comment: This is PHP, question was about JavaScript. How does that answer it?